# spring cloud stream kafka streams DLQ

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, stream, cloud

I am using Apache Kafka 2.7.0 with Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams.

In my Spring Cloud Stream (Kafka Streams) application, I have configured my application.yml to use the sendToDlq mechanism when the messages in the input topic have deserialization errors :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: processor      
      bindings:         
        processor-in-0:
          destination: input-topic
          consumer:
            dlqName: input-topic-dlq
        processor-out-0:
          destination: output-topic       
      kafka:
        streams:
            binder:
              deserialization-exception-handler: sendToDlq
            configuration:
              metrics.recording.level: DEBUG
            brokers:
              - localhost:9092
```

I start my application and I do not see this topic existing. The documentation states that the DLQ topic will be created if not present.

If I try to consume from the DLQ topic, I get an error as below :

```
kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic input-topic-dlq --property print.value=true --property print.key=true --from-beginning
[2021-03-19 10:17:09,936] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-console-consumer-85295-1, groupId=console-consumer-85295] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 2 : {input-topic-dlq=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE} (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

At this instant, when I query Zookeeper ls /brokers/topics then I see the Topic created.

Now, I try to POST a non-JSON message to the input-topic ( My default Deserializer is JSON).

**BUT I cannot see any messages in the input-topic-dlq topic created.**

**What is strange is that I can see messages in the default "error.input-topic-dlq.appId" topic.**

Am I doing something wrong here ?

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue. From what I saw, consumer properties provided within `spring.cloud.stream.bindings` are resolved to `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.ConsumerProperties` which does not have `dlqName` field. Only `org.springframework.cloud.stream.binder.kafka.properties.KafkaConsumerProperties` seems to have it but it seems to be used only for `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.bindings` consumer properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to figure that out. There seems to be a typo in current documentation for Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Streams Binder.

Destination for binding should be on `spring.cloud.streams.bindings` level ike you already have but consumer properties specific to the implementation should be on `spring.cloud.streams.kafka.streams.bindings` level.

So your configuration should look like this:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: processor      
      bindings:         
        processor-in-0:
          destination: input-topic
        processor-out-0:
          destination: output-topic       
      kafka:
        streams:
            binder:
              deserialization-exception-handler: sendToDlq
            bindings:
              processor-in-0:
                consumer:
                  dlqName: input-topic-dlq
            configuration:
              metrics.recording.level: DEBUG
            brokers:
              - localhost:9092
```